# Delphi 11.2 FireDAC writing to database

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-11-alexandria

Previously, in Delphi 11.1, when writing to a database my code worked as intended. Now, after updating to Delphi 11.2, there is a problem when writing a record to a field with a '%' in the field name. Creating the field works fine but adding a a record to a field with a '%' in the name causes the following error:

> ERROR: near ",": syntax error

When changing the '%' symbol, writing a record to the field works fine.

```
fieldbyname('test_%').asInteger := x;  //Causes syntax error
fieldbyname('test_pc').asInteger := x; //works as intended
```

I have also tried reading GetFieldNames() and this reads the field names as intended.

I just want to know why using a '%' symbol in the field name causes a syntax error?

Comment: Probably macro expansion has been added to field names? Have a look at the documentation there https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)

Comment: Try setting `FormatOptions.QuoteIdentifiers` to true. In some cases it is required to have column names properly quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing FDConnection or FDQuery or FDTable

```
RessourceOptions.MacroExpand:=false;
RessourceOptions.MacroCreate:=false;
```

Comment: I added to all 3; FDConnection, FDQuery and FDTable but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: I try this 2 syntax  (database Firebird)
 var n : string :='col%';

 fdtable1.FieldByName(n).AsInteger:=2;
 fdtable1.FieldByName('col%').AsInteger:=3; 
 
// Works without error

Answer (score 1):

I recommend escaping it by using a second '%'.

```
fieldbyname('test_%%').asInteger := x;
```